# How do I redirect a user using Apache Rewrite, to the fully qualified domain name?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm really new to apache mod_rewrite module.  I have a page called `http://abc` in my company intranet.  I want users to be redirected to `http://abc.somecompanyname.com` whenever they type `http://abc` to the URL bar.  Could someone please provide and example or point me in the right direction.

I figure this should be quite an easy question to answer.  Thanks everyone for you inputs.

-Mark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could accomplish that with a VirtualHost definition as simple as this, on the server handling requests for abc:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName abc
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://abc.somecompanyname.com/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: can we redirect him without changin URL? For instance, if I write http://mywebsite.example.com/a it will redirect the query to http://localhost:7777/a without changing the url of my browser?

Comment: rsabir: What you are asking is usually referred to as a proxy not a redirect

Comment: While this is the accepted answer, and does work, please see the better answer below by @ssc, using the `Redirect` directive.

Answer (score 12):

Quote from [Apache 2.4 documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost):

> The very best way to solve this doesn't involve mod_rewrite at all, but rather uses the Redirect directive placed in a virtual host for the non-canonical hostname(s).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName undesired.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com notthis.example.com

  Redirect / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This does require another virtual host, but there's no shortage of those. The solution works very well for me - and I like how redirection of 'unwanted' hosts and configuration of the canonical host are separated.

Comment: Thats working great, even the path names and get parameters are being redirected.

Comment: this is a better solution than the accepted answer. You really don't wanna be messing with rewrites too much. Best to leave rewrites as last resort.

Answer (score 2):

I found the advise in the Apache2 [URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html) worked better.

I ended up with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^foo\.bar\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$ 
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://foo.bar.com/$1 [L,R]
```

The "RewriteEngine on" line wasn't included in the Apache2 example. Maybe it's usually on by default but in my case I needed to add it.